# Global.asax Not Writing to Application EventLog Source

Tags: .net, httphandler, global-asax, event-log

I am having an issue in an HttpHandler when an exception gets thrown and handled by `Application_Error()` within my global application file (`global.asax`).  I am trying to write the `exception.Message` in my application's EventLog source.

And to clarify before you ask, yes the EventLog source exists.  The problem I'm having is that the exception itself doesn't write to my application's EventLog Source (for the sake of this example we'll say the event log source is named `HttpEndpoint`), but instead logs itself to the ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0 event log source.

Is there any way around this without doing away with global.asax's `Application_Error()` method, wrapping the method that executes before this error is thrown in a `try{}catch{}` and writing to the application's event log source in that manner?

The code in `Application_Error()` is pretty darn straight-forward:

```
  protected void Application_Error( object sender, EventArgs e )
  {
     var exception = Server.GetLastError();

     if ( exception == null )
     {
        return;
     }

     // try casting exception to known types for more specific event log entries
     var msmqOutputQueueWriteFailedException = exception as OutputMessageQueueWriteFailedException;

     if ( msmqOutputQueueWriteFailedException != null )
     {
        _windowsEventLog.LogFatal( _eventLogSource, string.Format( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "MSMQ Message Send Failure: {0} - InnerException Message: {1}", msmqOutputQueueWriteFailedException.Message, msmqOutputQueueWriteFailedException.InnerException.Message ) );
     }

     _windowsEventLog.LogError( _eventLogSource, String.Format( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Global Exception was thrown: {0}", exception.Message ), exception );
  }
```

The event log source of `HttpEndpoint` is held as an `<AppSetting>` within the Web.Config file, and is assigned to the `_eventLogSource` member in `global.asax`.  I also do other logging within the application to the same event log source (outside of `global.asax`), and that all works just fine and dandy.

Any ideas? Any help / feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did some experimenting...this seems to occur because of the cast from `Exception` to `OutputMessageQueueWriteFailedException`.

If I don't attempt to cast the exception type, and just let the exception's message get written to the event log in the `_windowsEventLog.LogError()` line instead of `_windowsEventLog.LogFatal()`, it gets written to the event log source I want.

I'm not quite sure why exactly that is.  Any elaborations on this topic are welcomed!